# Как реализовать ввод даты пользователем целиком за один раз?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Пишу функцию, где человеку надо угадать загаданную мной дату. У меня получается реализовать это через поочерёдный ввод дня, месяца и года, вот так это выглядит на примере. Но как можно сделать так, чтобы он за один раз ввёл дату целиком и она засчиталась как верная? Чтобы он не писал 6 отдельно, 6 отдельно, 2022 отдельно, а мог сразу написать 06/06/2022 или 06.06.2022.

```
a = "6"
b = "6"
c = "2022"
d = datetime.strptime(a + "/" + b + "/" + c, '%d/%m/%Y')
running = True

def dr():

    while running:
        guess = str(input('Угадайте день: '))

        if guess == a:
            print('Угадал')
            break
        if guess != a:
            print('Нет')

    while running:
        guess = str(input("Угадайте месяц: "))

        if guess == b:
            print('Угадал')
            break
        if guess != b:
            print('Нет')

    while running:
        guess = str(input("Угадайте год: "))

        if guess == c:
            print('Угадал')
            break
        if guess != c:
            print('Нет')

    if d:
        print("Конец")
    else:
        print("Нет")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то очень странное вы пишете. С одной стороны в вашем коде есть и `strptime` и `input`, а с другой - `как можно сделать так, чтобы он за один раз ввёл дату целиком`.  Вы что, выложенный код откуда-то содрали целиком и не думая?
Вот вам "скелет" программы-угадайки, где дата должна вводиться единой строкой, например `6/6/2022`,  а уж под свою задачу доводите ее сами:

```
import datetime
a = "6"
b = "6"
c = "2022"
dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(input('Введите дату'),'%d/%m/%Y')
if int(a)==dt.day: 
    print("Молодец, угадал день")
if int(b)==dt.month: 
    print("Молодец, угадал месяц")
if int(c)==dt.year: 
    print("Молодец, угадал год")
```